# Append list with NULLs to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, named-entity-recognition

I am using an NER library ([entity](https://github.com/trinker/entity)) to extract person names from sentences in a data frame.

If I run:

```
library(entity)
dat <- data.frame(texts=c('Henry went home', 'Drive a car', 'Two snowmen'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
person_entity(dat$texts)
```

I get a list of extracted names:

```
> person_entity(dat$texts)
[[1]]
[1] "Henry"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

How can I append this list as an additional column to my data frame? The additional column could be a list of the extracted names, or even just the length of the list, e.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(texts=c('Henry went home', 'Drive a car', 'Two snowmen'), person_count=c(1,0,0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `lengths` to get the length of individual elements in the list.

```
dat$person_count <- lengths(person_entity(dat$texts))
```

Comment: Wow, that is super straightforward. Thank you! Every other method I found got rid of the NULLs.